# Wants to create an record store in J2me Application as soon as the application starts

Tags: java, java-me, recordstore

working on a j2me project... what i need to do is create a record store from a preexisting xml file (in d jar itself) so i can read and write data from it..... and wants to do this as sson as the application starts pls help.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write following code in `startMIDlet()` method

```
RecordStore recordStore = RecordStore.openRecordStore("recordstorename", true);
String data="data";
recordStore.addRecord(data.getBytes("UTF-8");, 0, data.getBytes().length);
```

Comment: @vipul you are always welcomed to mark this as an answer if it is :) , you are welcome btw